# Check if a string contain Error 404

Tags: java

What's a simple method of checking if a string contain `error 404`? 
The string was built from HttpGet.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should better check the status code, the result string of a HTTP request is not guaranteed to contain the error code, if the status is 404.

If it's Apache HTTP client (which it looks like, because you mentioned `HttpGet`):

```
get = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com");
response = client.execute(get);
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
    System.out.println("404 - Not found!");
}
```

Comment: Yes I can easily find this with my HttpGet, but this just for testing purpose. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about the String method [contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)? No fuzz. If you want to do some more advanced search regex might be needed.

Code:

```
String s = "Foo error 404 bar";
System.out.println(s.contains('error 404');
```

prints `true`.

Note that this is not a good way to find errors (see Udo Klimaschewski's answer for example).

Comment: what if the return string of http-get is something like _"Error 404 is an error code that you see when a requested file is not found. It is..."_? An article explaining Error 404. This is not trivial as you suggest. Http response must be analyzed and then '404' can pe parsed.

Comment: @ivanovic That's not at all what the OP asked about. He wanted to know how to check if a string contains a certain sequence. So yes, it is as trivial as I suggested :p You might want to post this as a comment to the question though.

Comment: Since this for testing purpose, contains does the job. thank you